# Assign images to the elements of a pandas dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe, which one of the columns are images (single channel uint8 2d images in the numpy arrays format).
I am iterating thorugh the rows with iterrows(), and processing the images and I want to assing the results (other image, in the same format) to the elements of other column of the dataframe. I have a column for the images.

```
for index,row in df.iterrows():
    image=df['image']
    processed=process_image(image)
    df.loc[index,'processed_image']=processed
```

However, when I try to use either .loc or .at (or .iloc, .iat), face an error like this (respective for .loc and .at):

ValueError: cannot set using a multi-index selection indexer with a different length than the value
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

Probably loc and at are expecting a single value, they expect that arrays are meant to fill several indexes of the pandas dataframe. But I dont want that, I want the array as a single element.

I couldnt find the exact questino elsewhere in the internet. The closest I found as already initializing the dataframe with arrays elements by hand, not assingning in an iterrows.

Anyone know how to solve? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a new column as a function of the existing columns via the `.apply()` method e.g.

```
df['new_col'] = df.apply(lambda row: ..., axis=1)
```

Comment: That seems to work. However, I have thousands of rows, and the processing time is very long, and in each iteration I want to save the results(the entire updated dataframe). That why I wanted to do it in iterrows. 
If I save to file inside of the function called by the lambda function, will it save the updated dataframe for every row, like I wish?

Comment: Personally I would do the image processing distributed, storing image inputs and results as files and how the file names in the DF, not do the image processing in pandas.